# Newton's Method and Julia sets and the Douady rabbit. What's the relation?

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, complex-dynamics

I have question about Newton's method and the [Douady rabbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douady_rabbit).

I know that :

- The Douady rabbit is a Julia set with a specific choice of the complex number $c$ in the polynomial $z^2+c$
- The rabbit is the set of all initial points for which Newton's method does not converge to any root in the polynomial $P(x) = (z-a+1/2)(z+a+1/2)(z-1)$.

But I don't understand what's the relation between them ?

And what is the relation between the two polynomials ?

Also, what's the relation between the convergence of Newton's method and the 
convergence of the norm of $z$ in the Julia set?

Comment: I tried to edit to correct spelling, punctuation, etc., but I didn't feel comfortable guessing what "inials point" meant.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews inials → initial

Comment: That was my guess, but I wasn't comfortable with the guess since I didn't know what "initial point" meant in this context. :) @AndrésCaicedo

Comment: Is the parameter $a$ some specific value?

Comment: Douady's rabbit is the Julia set of the quadratic $f_c(z)=z^2+c$, where $c$\approx-0.122561 + 0.744862 i$ is chosen precisely so that $f_c^3(0)=(c^2+c)^2+c=0$. I'm certain there are polynomials whose corresponding Newton's method function would have similar dynamics. I guess you're asking if there such a polynomial in that particular family?

Comment: When you use newton method you will begin with intilal point to start the Algorithm ; that's what i mean

Comment: yes Mark McClure ; i'm looking for a relation

Answer (score 0):

> what's the relation between the convergence of Newton's method and the convergence of the norm of zz in the Julia set?

Douady rabbit is a set of [nonescaping points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escaping_set) which is the basin of attraction of period 3 orbit:

$$\{z: f_c^3(z)=z\}$$

One can find such orbit using :

- Newton ( iterative) method  : $z_{n+1}=z_n-{f_c(z)\over f_c'(z)}$
- iterating : $z_{n+1} = f_c(z_n)$ and checking its norm ( bailout test ) because if [$|z|>2$ then z is allways escaping](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890190/mandelbrot-sets-and-radius-of-convergence) ( it is called escape time method )

Zeros of both methods should be the same but [basins will be  different because these are different iterative methods of finding roots](http://folk.uib.no/ssu029/Pdf_file/Varona02.pdf)

Comment: yes that's what i know but i'm looking for the relation between the two points

Comment: IMHO relation is that this is the same set and you can use 2 different methods. Can you describe more what relation do you mean ? Where did you find your info about Newton methed ? ( ref)

Comment: I found that in this linkhttp://images.math.cnrs.fr/La-methode-de-Newton-et-son.html  he begin with the newton method then he goes to Julia set and i didn't understand the connection he said that this results from the theorem of renormalisation of Douady

Comment: Perhaps i could ask what's the relation between the constant a and c ?

Comment: zeros of P(x) are {-1, -a+1/2, a+1/2) and zeros of f(x) are {0, c, f(c)} so smth is wrong

Comment: because  c = -0.122561166876654  +0.744861766619744 i