# Divergence of $z_{n+1}=(z_n)^2+c$ if there exists $n_0$ such that $z_{n_0} \geq 2$

Tags: induction, divergence-operator

Let $z_{n+1}=(z_n)^2+c$ and suppose there exists $n_0$ such that $z_{n_0} > 2$. I want to show by induction that
$$
\left|z_n\right| > 2^{n-n_0+1} \text{ for }n \geq n_0
$$
For $n=n_0$, we have $\left|z_{n_0}\right| > 2$.
Suppose that it is true to a certain $N>n_0$ then
$$
\left|z_{n+1}\right|=\left|\left(z_n\right)^2+c\right| > \left|\left|z_n\right|^2-\left|c\right|\right| > \left|2^{2n-2n_0+2}-\left|c\right|\right|=2^{n+1-n_0+1}\left|2^{n-n_0}-\frac{\left|c\right|}{2^{n-n_0+1}}\right|
$$
How can I conclude from there since $c \in \mathbb{C}$ is unknown ?

Comment: You mean $|z_n| \ge 2$?

Comment: Divide into two cases: $|c|\leq 2$ and $|c|>2$.

Comment: There must be something missing. If $c = -2$ and $z_n=2$ then $z_{n+1} = 2$

Comment: @MartinR I would think we actually want $|z_{n_0}|>2$.

Comment: @Arthur: Even then: $c=-2$, $z_n=2.1 > 2$, $z_{n+1} = 2.41 \not\gt 4$

Comment: @MartinR At least from there it diverges. For $|z_{n_0}|=2$ it might not diverge at all. But yes, you can make it arbitrarily slow at first by setting $z_{n_0}=2+\varepsilon$ for some very small $\varepsilon$, so the result isn't true.

Comment: Is it true for $z_{n_0} > 2$ ?

Comment: @Atmos: No, as you can see in my last comment. It *is* true that $|z_{n_0}| > 2$ implies $z_n \to \infty$, that is a well-known property of the Mandelbrot set, if I remember correctly.

Comment: That's what I want to prove but the minoration i get is wrong so ? How can i prove the statement you mention ?

Comment: @Atmos: http://mrob.com/pub/muency/escaperadius.html, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#cite_ref-14

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890190/mandelbrot-sets-and-radius-of-convergence